# Fetch address from the local json

Tags: ios, json

I have code like this and json file is of below format and want to fetch from the local file

The json format :

```
{"":[{"name":"","phone":"","address":"","landmark":"","mainarea":""}
```

The code:

```
func loadAllContacts(){
        let cityCode = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "selectedLocationCode")
        mainArray = self.loadJSONData(fileCode: cityCode as! String).allValues as! [[String : AnyObject]]
        for i in 0..<mainArray.count{

            if let dict  = mainArray[i] as [String:AnyObject]?{

                for (key,_) in dict{

                    self.allContactsArray[key] = dict[key]

                }
            }
        }
        let contacts = allContactsArray as NSDictionary
        allContactNames = contacts.allKeys as NSArray
        print(allContactNames)
        print(allContactsArray)
    }
```

Comment: Do not use NSStuff in Swift

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON format is Invalid. Maybe, this is correct JSON that you want isn't it?

```
{
    "": [
        {
            "name": "",
            "phone": "",
            "address": "",
            "landmark": "",
            "mainarea": ""
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: need to fetch address from the above json for this below code:func loadAllContacts(){
        let cityCode = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "selectedLocationCode")
        mainArray = self.loadJSONData(fileCode: cityCode as! String).allValues as! [[String : AnyObject]]
        for i in 0..<mainArray.count{
            
            if let dict  = mainArray[i] as [String:AnyObject]?{
                
                for (key,_) in dict{
                    
                    self.allContactsArray[key] = dict[key]

                }
            }
        }

Comment: Did you really parse the JSON data correctly by `self.loadJSONData(fileCode: cityCode as! String).allValues as! [[String : AnyObject]]`?

Comment: In addition, If Swift version is 3.0 or later,  you should use `Any` instead of `AnyObject` and do not use the type with `NS` prefix.

Comment: Yeah,am not able to fetch any data. the app is getting crashed

Comment: Check if the format of your JSON data is correct. If your local JSON is  `{"":[{"name":"","phone":"","address":"","landmark":"","mainarea":""}`, you are not able to fetch data, because the format of JSON is not correct.

Comment: I have checked the json format then also app is crashing,it will be good that if i get complete explanation

Comment: App is crashing particularly at 4th linefunc loadAllContacts(){
        let cityCode = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "selectedLocationCode")
    ( 4thline)   mainArray = self.loadJSONData(fileCode: cityCode as! String).allValues as! [[String : AnyObject]]
        for i in 0..<mainArray.count{
            
            if let dict  = mainArray[i] as [String:AnyObject]?{
                
                for (key,_) in dict{
                    
                    self.allContactsArray[key] = dict[key]

                }
            }
        }:

Comment: What's the error message?
And you should use `Any` instead of `AnyObject` in Swift3.0 or later.

Comment: What is your XCode version and Swift version?

Comment: Please print the value of `mainArray`, after running `mainArray = self.loadJSONData(fileCode: cityCode as! String).allValues as! [[String : AnyObject]]`.

Comment: thank you Kazunori ,now the json data is visible ,but am not able to fetch information ..from popup

Comment: That' good!
Please show me the implementation of `self.loadJSONData(fileCode: cityCode as! String)` method.